# JDBC transactions. Как это работает?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, transaction

Подскажите пожалуйста, должно ли это вообще работать? Я знаю что можно сделать поле уникальным в базе, но нужно чтобы работало так. Записывается в базу все сразу, вместо того чтобы записалась одна запись, а остальные не прошли. Игрался с уровнями изоляции, работает только на сериалайзбл, но при этом летят эксепшны и если мне нужно будет добавить допустим 2 и более записей, с разными значениями email - все равно полетят эксепшны и добавится только самая первая, так что serializeble не вариант.

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    new Thread(new Thready("fuckthisshit")).start();
    new Thread(new Thready("fuckthisshit")).start();
    new Thread(new Thready("fuckthisshit")).start();
    new Thread(new Thready("fuckthisshit")).start();

}

static class Thready implements Runnable {
    private String name;

    public Thready(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/fp_db", "root", "root");
            connection.setAutoCommit(false);
            connection.setTransactionIsolation(Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_UNCOMMITTED);
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email =?");
            preparedStatement.setString(1, name);
            if (!preparedStatement.executeQuery().next()) {
                PreparedStatement preparedStatement1 = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO users (email) VALUES (?)");
                preparedStatement1.setString(1, name);
                preparedStatement1.executeUpdate();
                preparedStatement1.close();
            }else {
                connection.rollback();
            }
            connection.commit();
            preparedStatement.close();
            connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Какие иксепшоны?

Comment: Опишите исходную задачу. И детально опишите чем не угодило уникальное поле?

Comment: MySQLTransactionRollbackException: Deadlock found when trying to get lock;

Comment: @OlegDerivedmed попробуйте убрать блок else и rollback: вы ведь только делаете селект до попадания else, вам нечего ролбэчить.

Comment: @AndreyDorohovich Та я уже как только не делал, ничего не помогает :(

Comment: @AntonShchyrov есть таблица, допустим с юзерами. В ней, помимо прочих, есть поле "is_active" которое булеан. Есть модераторы, которые могут делать апдейт на эту табличку. Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы апдейт на 1 юзера можно было сделать только в том случае, когда все его отношения имеют false в этом поле. А если 2 модератора одновременно попытаются поменять Разные записи в этой табличке, но у одного юзера, то нужно сделать сначала проверку, не появилось ли у него true в том поле во всей табличке. Т. е. открываю транзакцию - проверяю селектом, если резалтсет пустой - апдейчу что мне нужно.

Comment: `все его отношения имеют false в этом поле` расшифруйте эту фразу. Пока я вижу в ней бессвязный набор слов

Comment: Я не вижу, никаких попыток обновлений. Я вижу, что вы пытаетесь вставить запись с e-mail, если такой записи нет в базе. Это делается по другому.

Comment: @OlegDerivedmed у вас вылетает MySQLTransactionRollbackException, вероятнее всего, если вы уберете rollback, тогда такой ошибки не будет. Возможно, будет другая, придется и с ней разобраться

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Табличка отношений ( many - many). Вобщем-то селект, который в транзакции все равно не будет ждать коммита, а сразу выполнится, по этому так это не будет работать, как мне хотелось бы.

Comment: Понять бы, что вам хочется. А то код публикуете один, задачу описываете другую, а термины используете третьи

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Все нормально я описал. Самое первое что я напсал, должен ли работать этот код? И предвидя ответы "а-ля" юзай уникальное значение сразу сказал что это не подходит. Нужно чтобы работало так как я в самом начале описал, а для чего это нужно - не имеет значения по сути. Вопрос был простой, должно ли это работать. Вот и все.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте этот код

```
static class Thready implements Runnable {
    private static final String JDBC_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/fp_db";
    private static final String USERNAME = "root";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "root";

    private String name;

    public Thready(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(JDBC_URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD)) {
           conn.setAutoCommit(false);

           if (!isUserAlreadyExist(name, conn)) {
               insertUser(name, conn);
           }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private boolean isUserAlreadyExist(String email, Connection conn) throws SQLException {
        try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?")) {
            stmt.setString(1, email);

            return stmt.executeQuery().next();
        }
    }

    private void insertUser(String email, Connection conn) throws SQLException {
        try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO users (email) VALUES (?)")) {
            stmt.setString(1, email);
            stmt.execute();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            conn.rollback();
        }
    }
}
```